# Moved to VS2019, virtual destructor option no longer there

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, visual-studio-2019

Since moving to Visual Studio 2019, when adding a item class there is no longer an option for virtual destructor. Is there an option to re-enable it?

I don't really know how I should compensate for this.
Ty in advance

**before:**

[image: Before]

**Now:**

[image: After]

Comment: A better idea is to use your own code snippet. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2019

Comment: I will learn to make my own. I'm new to how vs2019 operates, and new to c++ in general so im carefully following a tutorial to learn. I don't understand deconstructors yet since i've never had to use them before. (I come from C, where you kinda just had the constructor for initializing struct variables lol). In this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXnhYBG0AEA he has this very straightforward option that now happens to be missing, and I am unsure how to procede. Any ideas?

Comment: The easy answer certainly is to just add the one liner manually. However, I feel there may be some interesting tidbits hidden here as to why MS decided to remove the option.

Comment: The misunderstanding here might be in the separation between the C++ language and Visual Studio's text editor functionality. You can skip this whole "add class" part and just type in the same text. The dialog is there to save you some typing, but `virtual` is just 7 letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, still dont know why the feature is gone.
But just add the deconstructor yourself.

Here's an example

```
class Game
{
public:
    Game();             //constructor
    virtual ~Game();    //destructor
};
```

Comment: You may be interested in Howard Hinnant's [How I Declare My `class` And Why](https://howardhinnant.github.io/classdecl.html) on class layout.